# Angular: input is undefined on NgOnInit

Tags: angular, input

I know the subject has been discussed, but I can’t find a solution to my problem in my case.
I have a parent component that returns my data that is passed to input.

ts parent component:

```
  public productList!: IDocumentProduct[];

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.orderService
          .getAllProducts()
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((productList) => {
            this.productList = productList;
          });
      }
```

HTML parent:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__search">
      <xen-order-form
        [productList]="productList"></xen-order-form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the child ts

```
@Input() set productList(value: IDocumentProduct[]) {
    this._products = value;
    this.finalValue = this.products;
  };

  public finalValue: IDocumentProduct[] = [];
  private _products!: IDocumentProduct[];

  get products(): IDocumentProduct[] {
    return this._products;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.finalValue);  // undefined...
  }
```

How can I retrieve the value oh the Input() in the ngOnInit()

Thanks for help

Comment: In my opinion you are using the the non null assertion `!` in a way where you make things difficult for yourself. In reality, the attribute can be undefined, as long as the data is not loaded yet. I would recommend to use `?` instead. You would end up with some type errors, but after fixing them, you should have working solution.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would try to discourage the approach you are taking. If you are interested in performing some action in reaction to there being a value set by an Input, you would perform the action in the setter of the Input of interest. In your case, you would change your code to the following:

```
    @Input() set productList(value: IDocumentProduct[]) {
        this._products = value;
        this.finalValue = this.products;
        console.log(this.finalValue);
      };
```

The order of setting of the inputs isn't guaranteed. This is especially true if there are multiple inputs and they are set asynchronously.

There is a way to achieve what you want, but I would argue it is most likely an incorrect model to be following with Angular development. That would be to utilize the `*ngIf` directive in the parent component as follows:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="container__search">
      <xen-order-form *ngIf="productList"
        [productList]="productList"></xen-order-form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That way the child component will only be initialized if there is a value in the product list. I would discourage this for a few reasons though.

It is probable that with an array, it would hold an initial value of an empty array which will still cause the same problem you are seeing now. You could work around that by changing the boolean clause to `*ngIf="productList?.length"`. Then what if you want ngOnInit to only be fired when multiple inputs are set? You would need a more complex expression in the `*ngIf`. What if the inputs are set multiple times for whatever reason, etc, etc.

Comment: Agreed that `*ngIf` guarding the selector in the parent template isn't the way to go, but maybe mention the [`OnChanges` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) instead of doing everything in the setter?

Comment: @DM That is a good thing to mention, but to be honest, I've never really used that method in my ~7 yrs of Angular development. I haven't had a need for it and preferred to avoid it due to the fact that it is programmed against 'magic strings'.

Comment: Fair enough! There have been some native improvements (like exposing individual changes as properties instead of having to use the change name as an index: `changes.propertyName` instead of `changes['propertyName']`), but the keys in the changes array are not strongly typed. If you're interested, Netanel Basal is a wizard and has an article on this exact subject: [Create a Typed Version of SimpleChanges in Angular](https://netbasal.com/create-a-typed-version-of-simplechanges-in-angular-451f86593003).

Comment: I don't fully agree on discouraging the use of `*ngIf`. If there are a lot of inputs from different sources, I totally agree that it doesn't make sense. But if there is only one such input, and no further conditions need to be considered, why not keep it simple?

Comment: I'd argue that `*ngIf` in this case is patching the problem, not solving it. A full solution would be implementing the appropriate lifecycle hook (`OnChanges`) in your child component so that any time the bound data changes, the child component handles the new value. Deferring the creation of a component based on the flow of data extracts the responsibility for showing that data from the child and places it on the parent (the parent now has to manage when the child is showing because the child can't handle the case when its data isn't available yet).

Comment: It's not that the `*ngIf` approach is wrong (I've used the same trick many times), but it's just that - a trick. I'd personally prefer to leverage the framework rather than muddy the separation of responsibilities as long as that's an option. If you just need to make this code work and you're not overly worried about project structure/separation of concerns, by all means use `*ngIf`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going tochange my approach

Answer (score 0):

The `xen-order-form` component is constructed before loading of the data finished. As a result, on init, the data is not there yet. To delay rendering of the component you can simply use `*ngIf`:

```
<xen-order-form
  *ngIf="productList !== undefined"
  [productList]="productList"></xen-order-form>
```